# Swift URL Response is nil

Tags: session, swift, return, nsurl, null

I have created a custom DataManager class. Inside it I want to fetch data in a method and return an NSData object to convert to JSON afterwards.

I have tried to get the data using the completionHandler but no luck:

```
class func fetchData() -> NSData? {
    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession(),
        result = NSData?()
    let DataURL : NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://...file.json")!

    let sessionTask = session.dataTaskWithURL(DataURL, completionHandler: { (data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        result = data
    })
    sessionTask.resume()
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dataTask` runs asynchronously. That means that the completion handler closure will not be called by the time you return from `fetchData`. Thus, `result` will not have been set yet.

Because of this, you should not try to retrieve data synchronously from an asynchronous method. Instead, you should employ an asynchronous completion handler pattern yourself:

```
class func fetchData(completion: @escaping (Data?, Error?) -> Void) {
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let url = URL(string: "http://...file.json")!

    let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        completion(data, error)
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

And you'd call it like so:

```
MyClass.fetchData { data, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {
        print(error ?? "Unknown error")
        return
    }

    // use `data` here; remember to dispatch UI and model updates to the main queue
}

// but do not try to use `data` here

...
```

FYI, for the original pre-Swift 3 syntax, see [previous revision of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28868958/2).

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I still have a problem though. It seems these async methods have a low priority AKA they run last. I am using a table view and I need to fill an object Array before the main load functions (such as the ones that set the row count). How do I force these async function to run before these?

Comment: You generally do not try to have the tableview wait for the network request, but let it just go and find that `numberOfRowsInSection` is zero and conclude that there is nothing (yet) to be presented. And then, inside the `fetchData` completion handler (which is called after the network request is done), you populate the model objects and then tell the tableview to reload itself (e.g. `self.tableView.reloadData()`).